# Index shell script as application

Tags: command-line, search, autorun

So I made a shell script. I want to be able to open it as if it were an application (i.e: Hit super, type the script's name, hit enter, be happy). At this point it just displays the file in gedit. How do I make it auto run?

edit: To clarify. I have made the script executable. When I click it in nemo, it gives a little prompt asking me to run it, and it runs as expected.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and Desktop are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Create a desktop launcher to launch the script, and put it in your `.local/share/applications` folder. Desktop lauchers are text files that end with the `.desktop` extension. When places in the folder mentioned, they are automatically picked up by your application menu.

Such `.desktop`file must contain at least

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=<Name of your application like you want to see it in the menu>
Exec=<path to your executable>
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=<path to the icon>
```

Depending on what your script does, you may need to set `Terminal` to `true`. If set this way, the launcher will open your default terminal emulator, and run your script in the terminal emulator. Otherwise, it will be run in the background (where, eventually, it may open a GUI application).